# wix installer change ui language

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, localization, wix

Since the default language for the WiX installler UI is english, I'd like to change to another langue like german or something. I'm sure the must be some predefined langue packs, coming with the toolkit?

**Is there a way can I change the language of the WiXs default installer UI?**

(I am using the Visual Studio (2012) Addin)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply add a parameter to the WiX linker (*light.exe*): `-cultures:culture-code`
You can find all culture codes [here](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/do-you-speak-english/).

When using Viual Studio simply open the project properties and add the `-cultures:culture-code` to the linkers parameters:

[image]

Comment: The url with the culture codes is now broken. The correct url is: https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/do-you-speak-english/