# Have WiX/Burn detect the required version of .NET Framework

Tags: wix, burn

How can I have [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) detect that the required .NET 4.5 framework is installed and if not notify the user prior to launching my custom UI that the install requires .NET 4.5 to run?

Without the prerequisite check my custom UI (BootStrapperApplication) will fail to load.

I do not want to install only prompt that it is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Bundle.wxs file (or where ever you have the `<Bundle>` defined), add this:

```
<bal:Condition Message="Add your message here">NETFRAMEWORK40FULL</bal:Condition>
```

For example, I use the following message to provide a clickable link the user can use to download the needed installer:

```
<?define NetFx40WebLink = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=182805 ?>
<bal:Condition Message="Microsoft .NET 4 Full Framework is required. Please download and install it from &lt;a href=&quot;$(var.NetFx40WebLink)&quot;&gt;$(var.NetFx40WebLink)&lt;/a&gt; then re-run this installer.">NETFRAMEWORK40FULL</bal:Condition>
```

And the result looks like this:

[image: download required screenshot]

Comment: Any clues as to how you defined the main caption for this dialog?  i.e. 'Microsoft .NET Framework required for xxx setup'?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot change the main caption (unless you edit the WiX source yourself).

Comment: NETFRAMEWORK40FULL is an MSI variable, so surely you can't use it in a Bundle? I've just tried this to be sure, and setup always fails, even if .NET is installed - presumably because the NETFRAMEWORK40FULL variable is always false

Comment: Do you know how to force the language to english always (independent from the users' locale settings)? If locale is set to german, then the upper text "Microsoft .NET Frame..." is in german.

Comment: I'm not positive, but you might try forcing the culture of your installer to english and see if that passes over to the .net installer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12407004/682840

Answer (score 7):

The currently accepted answer doesn't actually work, as MSI properties aren't available in a bundle.

This example checks for .NET Framework 4.6.1.
Add references to the NetFxExtension and UtilExtension in your Wix tag:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" 
 xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
```

Define some properties indicating the .NET version you require (I found the release by trawling through [this repo](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib)):

```
<?define NetFx461MinRelease = 394254 ?>
<?define NetFx461WebLink = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=671728 ?>
```

Finally, inside your bundle reference the registry check from the NetFx Extension and then perform the check manually.

```
<util:RegistrySearchRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/>

<bal:Condition Message="This product requires .NET Framework 4.6.1, please install it from &lt;a href=&quot;$(var.NetFx461WebLink)&quot;&gt;$(var.NetFx461WebLink)&lt;/a&gt;.">
  <![CDATA[NETFRAMEWORK45 >= $(var.NetFx461MinRelease)]]>
</bal:Condition>
```

Comment: This results in `error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixSearch:NETFRAMEWORK45'`.  The violation is on the registrysearchref line.

Comment: @Jon Do you have a reference to the WixNetFxExtension.dll in your WiX project?

Comment: This answer worked whereas the accepted one did not.